# TableLayoutPanel changing it's sizing

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a few `tablelayoutpanels` in my program in order to lay out different controls in rows. Until recently these were all working correctly, but after a change in server this is no longer the case. A potential cause is a change in screen resolution as I noticed similar problems on other computers running my program.

An example of this problem is shown below

[image]

Before the data rows are loaded (from database), the sizing is incorrect. A measurement using the VS designer shows that the size in figure 2 is correct. Interestingly, if I add a blank row to this table then the resizing doesn't happen.

```
public JobOpMainTable()
{
    DoubleBuffered = true;
    AutoSize = true;
    AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    DoubleBuffered = true;
    BackColor = Color.White;
    CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
    headers();
}

private void headers()
{
    string[] names = { "Operation", "Est Lab Hrs", "Est UM Hrs", "Act Lab Hrs", "Act UM Hrs" };
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) header(names[i], i);
}

private void header(string name, int col)
{
    Panel pan = new Panel();
    pan.Width = widths[col];
    pan.Height = 25;
    pan.BackColor = Color.Black;
    pan.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pan.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft sans serif", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
    txt.Text = name;
    txt.ReadOnly = true;
    txt.BackColor = Color.Black;
    txt.ForeColor = Color.White;
    txt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    txt.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    pan.Controls.Add(txt);
    Controls.Add(pan, col, 0);
}

private int newRow()
{
    int row = Controls.Count / 5;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Width = widths[i];
        txt.BackColor = Color.White;
        txt.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        txt.ReadOnly = true;
        txt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        txt.Margin = new Padding(0);
        txt.Enter += new EventHandler(enterCell);
        txt.Leave += new EventHandler(leaveCell);
        Controls.Add(txt, i, row);
    }
    return row;
}
```

Above is the code I believe is relevant to the problem. The resizing occurs the first time `newRow()` is called when loading in data: each new box makes the column wider. Again though, the odd thing is this doesn't occur if I add a row from the constructor

Comment: RE:  "each new box makes the column wider".  Do you mean that after _every row_ the column it is added to widens?  So it keeps growing?  Or that it resizes just once and remains the same for every subsequent row?

Comment: The latter. In that each box added increases its column, but only for the first row

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel` cells are set to `AutoSize`?  If so then you would be describing the expected behavior.

Comment: They should autosize. But I don't think that should give this result - Both the header and the rows have panels holding the textbox which have their width set the same. Therefore I would expect the table to autosize to this width in both cases, not just the one. I use autosize to get the correct height

Comment: "Both the header and the rows have panels holding the textbox" <-- the code doesn't reflect this.  Only the header row appears to have Textboxes within Panels.

Comment: Ah, true. But that shouldn't make a difference. Both controls have their widths set, so why should it work for one type and not another

Comment: What happens after `NewRow` is called?  How is that row actually added to the `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: The second image is the 'correct' one. Measuring in designer shows this matches the set width. For some reason this does not happen with just the headers and also if I add a row from the constructor. the row is added in NewRow() -> Controls.Add()

Comment: Is it prior to display?  Is this a case of setting widths before actual rendering has occurred, thus not being scaled correctly to the form?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure I understand you there. I have tried setting the widths after I have added the controls to the table with no success

Comment: I mean, is the control already rendered (shown) onscreen when the widths are being set.  `AutoSize` requires knowing the size/scale of its container in order to work properly.  I.e. if you add the headers in construction, there is no basis for scale.  Then it's rendered on-screen and you add a row, which triggers resize at the proper rendered scale.

Comment: The widths are set before they are added. I don't think the problem will be here anyway as a Refresh() to redraw the table doesn't have any effect

Comment: The only thing that's obvious from the snippet is that you are thinking about this problem all wrong.  Assigning the Width and Height properties has no effect whatsoever when you set the Dock property.  Layout is purely determined by the TableLayoutPanel, we can't see what you did with it.  This should be a ListView btw.

Comment: I agree with you that in this instance a different control would be more appropriate, but I use this for consistency with my other tables which are more complicated. The thing that confuses me about this though is that all these worked as I wanted until yesterday